# Accessing function from the same class in a different file

Tags: python

I am trying to access a function from within a class that is within a different file.

My layout is:

```
Directory
   -> ClassFile.py
   -> _AFile.py
```

in ClassFile:

```
class TestClass:

    from ._AFile import test_1, test_2, test_3

    def __init__(self):


    def RunAllTests(self):
        self.test_1()
        self.test_2()
        self.test_3()


    @staticmethod
    def __DoSomething(a, b):
        return a + b
```

in _AFile:

```
def test_1(self):
    self.__DoSomething

def test_2(self):
    self.__DoSomething

def test_3(self):
    self.__DoSomething
```

This is what I want to do but cannot as I get:
AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute '__DoSomething'

How can I access the static method from TestClass within AFile?

Comment: Can you include the complete definition of `_AFile`, atleast the member listing?

Comment: Okay, I have done now

Comment: It is because `test_1` exists in `_AFile`, there is no `__DoSomething` in `_AFile`. You'll have to import `TestClass` in `_AFile`. Also you'll have to call it as `TestClass.__DoSomething` as it is static.

Comment: If I try

from .ClassFile import TestClass

and use TestClass.__DoSomething()

I get:

ImportError: cannot import name 'TestFeaturesClass' from partially initialized module 'Test.Tests_Features.test_features' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: You're imagining things the wrong way around. I think you're picturing TestClass importing AFile, and so when the functions of AFile are invoked they do so "inside" TestClass, so self refers to TestClass. This isn't correct. If you import a module, self will always refer to its own class (it's not clear here if AFile has a class). What you need to do is think of it the other way around: in AFile import TestClass, and in AFile call TestClass.DoSomething() (Don't forget the parentheses)

Comment: @GMoney the clue is in the error message: circular import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods which start with `__` are class-private and they are mangled and so you cant access them when importing form a different file.

Official Docs:

> **__***
>
> Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the
> context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to
> help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and
> derived classes. See section Identifiers (Names).

### Fix

Change `__DoSomething` to `_DoSomething`

You are spreading the implementation of class `TestClass` into two files `ClassFile.py` and `_AFile.py`. In such a case you need to put `__init__.py` (empty file) inside the module.

### Fix

Your directory structure should look like below

```
mymodule
   --> __init__.py
   --> ClassFile.py
   --> _AFile.py
```

ClassFile.py

```
class TestClass:

    from ._AFile import test_1, test_2, test_3

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def RunAllTests(self):
        self.test_1()
        self.test_2()
        self.test_3()


    @staticmethod
    def _DoSomething(a, b):
        result = a+b
        print (result)
        return result
```

_AFile.py

```
def test_1(self):
    self._DoSomething(1,2)

def test_2(self):
    self._DoSomething(2,3)

def test_3(self):
    self._DoSomething(4,5)
```

Testing:

```
from mymodule.ClassFile import TestClass
test = TestClass()
test.RunAllTests()
```

Output:

```
3
5
9
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a private method from outside its class declaration, and it happens that [python is doing some transformations under the hood](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#i-try-to-use-spam-and-i-get-an-error-about-someclassname-spam).

As explained in the link above, the private attributes and methods of a python class are modified under the form `_ClassName__attributename`. This is a protection to avoid collision with subclasses defining potentially the same attributes or methods.

As a result, to make your import work as you want, you have two possibilities:

- keep the method private, but use the generated method name from python
- Use protected methods to use in your secondary file.

The following files will show you both possibilities:

_AFile.py

```py
def test_1(self):
    # Express which private method you want to use
    self._TestClass__DoSomething()

def test_2(self):
    # Use a protected attribute only
    self._do_another_thing()
```

ClassFile.py

```py
class TestClass:

    from _AFile import test_1, test_2

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def RunAllTests(self):
        self.test_1()
        self.test_2()

    @staticmethod
    def __DoSomething():
        print("done something")

    @staticmethod
    def _do_another_thing():
        print("done another thing")
```

Execution:

```py
>>> from ClassFile import TestClass
>>> TestClass().RunAllTests()
done something
done another thing
```